# UnboundedLocalError in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm getting UnboundedLocalError in django.
Exception-value:local variable 'comment_form' refrenced before assignment.

I used ModelForms from forms to create a comment form.So this is the views.py file of the comment form.

```
def post_detail(request,year,month,day,post):
'''post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=post,status='published',publish__year=year,
                       publish__month=month,publish__day=day)'''
try:
    post=Post.published.get(slug=post)
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Post Doesnot Exist")
#list of active comments for the post
comments=post.comments.filter(active=True)
if request.method=='POST':
    #a comment was posted
    comment_form=CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        #create comment object but dont save to database yet
        new_comment=comment_form.save(commit=False)
        #assign the current post to the comment
        new_comment.post=post
        #save the comment to database
        new_comment.save()
    else:
        print (form.error)
        comment_form=CommentForm()

return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post':post,'comments':comments,'comment_form':comment_form})
'''return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post':post})'''
```

template detail.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<p class="date">
Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
</p>
{{ post.body|linebreaks }}
(% with comments.count as total_comments %}
<h2>
{{total_comments}}comment{{total_comments|pluralize}}
</h2>
{% endwith %}
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="comment">
  <p class="info">
     Comment {{forloop.counter }} by {{comment.name}}
     {{comment.created}}
  </p>
  {{comment.body|linebreaks}}
</div>
{%empty%}
  <p>There are nocomments yet.</p>
{% endfor %}
{% if new_comment %}
<h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
{% else %}
<h2>Add a new comment.</h2>
<form action="." method="post">
  {{comment_form.as_p }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
 </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment
class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
     name=forms.CharField(max_length=25)
     email=forms.EmailField()
     to=forms.EmailField()
     comments=forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.Textarea)

 class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model=Comment
        fields=('name','body')
```

I checked all the related question but still error occurs with this code.
so for this error i cant load my webpage

Comment: You have an indentation problem, the else clause in the view should be one indent to the left (and that `print` call shouldn't be there at all).

Answer (score 0):

You're only defining `comment_form` if your request is a POST.  You need to define it ( `comment_form=CommentForm()` ) outside of that `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you.Now i get the concept clearly.But after this problem is solved one more problem is there.Exception Value:'Invalid block tag on line 13: 'endwith', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?'.Now i'm getting this error.How to solve it

Comment: Try indenting your template for each section (i.e. {% tag %} / {% endtag %}).  Then if you template tags aren't nested properly it will be easier to see.